# Expanding an array within a structure in C

Tags: objective-c, c

I've got a question about what *I think* boils down to C syntax and memory considerations. I have a callback in an Objective-C class that processes some audio, and one of the arguments is `bufferListInOut`. It represents a mono audio signal that I'd like to convert to stereo. Here's my code:

```
static void tap_ProcessCallback(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap,
                            CMItemCount numberFrames,
                            MTAudioProcessingTapFlags flags,
                            AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut,
                            CMItemCount *numberFramesOut,
                            MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut){

    // Retrieve mono audio data into bufferListInOut
    MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, numberFrames, bufferListInOut, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Copy the mono channel's data
    float *channelLeft = malloc(numberFrames * sizeof(float));
    channelLeft = bufferListInOut->mBuffers[0].mData;

    // Attempt to create a second channel which is (currently) a copy of the first
    bufferListInOut->mNumberBuffers = 2; // 2 for stereo, 1 for mono
    bufferListInOut->mBuffers[1].mNumberChannels = 1;
    bufferListInOut->mBuffers[1].mDataByteSize = numberFrames * sizeof(Float32);
    bufferListInOut->mBuffers[1].mData = channelLeft;

    // Set number of frames out
    *numberFramesOut = numberFrames;
}
```

Some notes:

- In this code, the new channel is just a copy of the original, but in practice it will undergo some processing.
- The naming is a little weird, but `mNumberBuffers` is indeed meant to be 2 and `mNumberChannels` is meant to be 1.

This crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on a rendering thread down the line. So, my question is what is the right way to add a new buffer to this struct? I don't delve into C too often, so I'm sure I'm missing some basics here. Any pointers on this would be great. Thanks for reading.

Comment: What is your question? There is not a single one in this post.

Comment: This is complex stuff, but right off the bat, you allocate memory and assign it to `channelLeft` and then immediate reassign `channelLeft`, leaking memory.  I think you want `memcpy(channelLeft, bufferListInOut->mBuffers[0].mData, numberFrames * sizeof(float));`.

Comment: @Sanuuu Thanks for the comment. I just clarified the question.

Comment: Hi @trojanfoe, thanks for the explanation. It doesn't fix the crashing issue, but good to know re: the leak.

Comment: At the end of function `mBuffers[1].mData == mBuffers[0].mData` . Next code, trying release memory will do it twice on the same float* pointer

Comment: The next question is what is the size of `bufferListInOut->mBuffers`?  I doubt you can simply do `bufferListInOut->mNumberBuffers = 2;` then start happily writing to `bufferListInOut->mBuffers[1]`.  I expect `mBuffers` needs to be increased.  How is that done?  Find the documentation to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do what you are attempting, at least in the way you are trying to do it. The type `AudioBufferList` is declared as:

```
struct AudioBufferList { UInt32 mNumberBuffers; AudioBuffer mBuffers[1]; };
```

This is a classic C pattern for a *variable sized* struct. To create a struct for `N` buffers a *single* block of memory is allocated with the size:

```
sizeof(UInt32) + N * sizeof(AudioBuffer)
```

The address of that block is assigned to a `AudioBufferList *` variable and the field `mNumberBuffers` set to `N`. You **cannot** simply increase the `mNumberBuffers` to increase the size of the array, instead you must either allocate a new complete struct, or `realloc` the existing one - `realloc` increases the size of memory block if possible or allocates a new one and copies the existing data into it if not.

Given your `tap_ProcessCallback()` function is passed a `AudioBuuferList *` value and does not return one, there is no way it can change the size of the struct (i.e. the number of buffers) it is passed.

As pointed out in comments you are also doing pointer assignment when you intend to copy memory - see `memcpy` and friends.

So you need a redesign - your goal is possible, just not how and where you've attempted it.

HTH

Comment: Hi @CRD, thanks for this explanation, very helpful! Just to make sure I follow, when you say "there is no way [tap_ProcessCallback()] can change the size of the struct…need a redesign" are you saying that with the function arguments as they are (which we unfortunately have no control over), it's not possible to change the number of buffers?

Comment: Correct. The function is being passed the address of the callers `AudioBufferList`. As written it has no way to change the callers value for this address to that of a new, enlarged, struct.

Comment: You can change the caller value if you change the function parameter to `AudioBufferList **bufferListInOut` (of course, update code inside, and everywhere the function is called). Well... I still have the -50 error (kAudio_ParamError).